# MPLAB X IDE installation problem ubuntu 13.10

Tags: software-installation

Before upgrading to saucy, I had all my development IDEs and compilers being installed successfully in 13.04.

Now, ever since I have upgraded to saucy, I just simply can not install MPLAB X and the xc8 compiler. These files have a .run extension and were downloaded straight from the manufacturers.

I have tried chmod +x, chmod a+x, etc and no result.

Another thing to note is that my QT .run file executed and installed successfully. Anybody else facing this problem.

I am not new to linux, but still have no idea why this is happening. Could it be that since 13.10 has no ia32-libs since its multiarch? The MPLAB product website says to have ia32-libs installed. I did it for previous ubuntu versions, but since the package itself is absent, any other solution to get the installer to work?

**EDIT: Never mind that. Instead of the package ia32-libs, you now have "lib32z1". Simply install that and you should be able to install the package.
Hope this helps everyone.**

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Answer (score 1):

> 64-bit versions of Ubuntu and its derivatives do not include the 32-bit libraries required to run the installer. This may be true of other 64-bit distributions. Before the installer will run, you need to install the ia32-libs.

http://microchip.wikidot.com/mplab:linux64  :

Many recent versions of 64-bit Linux distributions such as Ubuntu, Xubuntu and other derivatives do not have the 32-bit libraries needed by Microchip's installers to run. Although the applications (MPLAB X IDE, MPLAB XC Compilers) are 64-bit applications, the installers are not. If you try to run an installer without the 32-bit libraries, nothing will happen at all.

To install the libraries, you can try the minimal installation:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

If the above doesn't work, you can install the full libraries (texted on Xubuntu 12.04):

> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

The full libraries take some time to install, but may prove useful if you install other programs from binaries too.

Comment: Like I mentioned before, there are no 32 bit libraries in 13.10 since its shifted to multiarch. I know the process of ia32-libs (i have mentioned this in the question above), but it simply does not exist as a package in ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Still have no idea why this is happening. Should I try a reinstall?